# How can i animate Barbutton in Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to animate `UIBarButtonItem`in he NavigationBar from left to right when i flip the view. How can i do this.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it shouldn't be done. You have no access to the UIBarButton that is the backing of the UIBarButtonItem - the item is used as a placeholder for this reason: you shouldn't be touching the view.

If you wanted to do it anyway, you have two options: either implement the button yourself, using UIButton and the -[UIBarButtonItem intWithCustomView:] method, or hit test the navigation bar for the button located at that location, and move it manually, but setting that view's frame.

May I stress I don't recommend the second option, as it is a major hack.

The first option would require you to Unset the button from the navigation bar, add it where it was on top of the navigation bar as a subview, then move it. Once moved, you'd remove it from the navigation bar, put it back in another UIBarButtonItem wrapper, and set it to the navigation item's right side animated.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11070043/168446

Essentially, there's another option (if you use iOS5): Use an animated `UIImage` as the image of the `UIBarButtonItem`.